# Separate multiple CONCAT columns

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
CONCAT_WS('<br>', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT events.ID, events.EVENT_NAME, events.start_datetime SEPARATOR '<br><br>')) AS all_ids
```

Which produces something like this:

```
1Some Event!2013-01-03 21:00:00<br><br>

14Another Event2012-12-31 19:00:00<br><br>

25Friday Event2013-01-10 21:00:00<br><br>
```

But I would like to separate each column with a `<BR>` as well so the result would look like this:

```
1<BR>
Some Event!<BR>
2013-01-03 21:00:00<br><br>

14<BR>
Another Event<BR>
2012-12-31 19:00:00<BR><BR>

25<BR>
Friday Event<BR>
2013-01-10 21:00:00<br><br>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) around each field:

```
CONCAT_WS('<br>', 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
            concat(events.ID, '<br>'), 
            concat(events.EVENT_NAME, '<br>'), events.start_datetime SEPARATOR '<br><br>')) AS all_ids
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CONCAT_WS('<br>', GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT events.ID + '<br>', events.EVENT_NAME + '<br>', events.start_datetime + '<br>' SEPARATOR '<br><br>')) AS all_ids
```

You might have to cast the columns to varchars before you can append the BR tag to the values

Comment: Thanks LastCoder! That's exactly what I was looking for :)))

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using GROUP_CONCAT then?
It would be more simple to query the columns and just output/format them as needed.

Comment: I cannot because they're being output as marker data. I had to combine multiple markers into one if I want an infobox to show all info.